# How to add a custom route with limited resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, action

My `friendships` controller needed at first only two actions, `create` and `destroy`, so I added the following in `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :friendships, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

However, I had to add a custom `drop` action to allow users to drop friendships requests.
Since I need only these three actions and I will not not use all the RESTful resources, I wonder if I can edit `config/routes.rb` as follows:

```
resources :friendships, only: [:create, :destroy] do
  member do
    post :request, action: :drop
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can; doing so will result in this routes:

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
request_friendship POST   /friendships/:id/request(.:format) friendships#drop
       friendships POST   /friendships(.:format)             friendships#create
        friendship DELETE /friendships/:id(.:format)         friendships#destroy
```